# check if a nested list contains a substring

Tags: python

How to check if a nested list contains a substring?

```
strings = [[],["one", "two", "three"]]
substring = "wo"

strings_with_substring = [string for string in strings if substring in string]

print(strings_with_substring)
```

this script just prints :

```
[]
```

how to fix it? output should be:

```
two
```

==

Sayse, solution you provided doesn't work for me. I am new to python. I am sure I am missing something here. any thoughts?

```
import re

s = [[],["one", "two", "three"]]
substring = "wo"

# strings_with_substring = [string for string in strings if substring in string]

strings_with_substring = next(s for sl in strings for s in sl if substring in s)

print(strings_with_substring)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to print? a boolean stating if the item exists or the containing elements?

Comment: output should be 'two'.

Comment: When you check your substring against the list containing those strings, you are only checking for containment of the list of strings. It will not perform a search for each substring in each string of that list. So, this: `substring in ["one", "two", "three"]` will be empty all the time, because it is checking for containment of the string "wo" for each element of the list. I would suggest to help you understand what is going on better, to not do this in a comprehension, but rather expand it step by step and print each line. It will help greatly.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing another level of iteration. Here is the looping logic without using a comprehension:

```
for sublist in strings:
    for item in sublist:
        if substring in item:
            print(item)
```

Roll that up to a comprehension:

```
[item for sublist in strings for item in sublist if substring in item]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for

```
next(s for sl in strings for s in sl if substring in s)
```

This outputs "two", if you want a list of all elements then change the `next` for your list comprehension with given ammendments, or likewise, change `next` to `any` if you just want a boolean result

Answer (score 0):

Since you said it should just `print` the string ~ You could use `itertools` to flatten your `list` and run it through a `filter` that you loop over.

```py
from itertools import chain

strings = [[], ['one', 'two', 'three']]

substring = 'wo'

for found in filter(lambda s: substring in s, chain.from_iterable(strings)):
    print(found)
```